# Does the series $\frac{2}{4-1}+\frac{4}{16-1}+\dots+\frac{2k}{4k^2-1}$ have a sum up to $\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, infinity, divergent-series

If there's one, then how do I find the sum?

I tried to rewrite the common term into partial fractions to see if it's a telescoping series but got a dead end there. How can I proceed now?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @DUO: No, but it is greater than $\frac 1{2k}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Fixed it: $\frac{2k}{4k^2-1}>\frac1{k^2}$, so due to the comparison test, it diverges.

Comment: @DUO:  but the sum of $\frac 1{k^2}$ does not diverge.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, I got it mixed up-- you're right: $\frac{2k}{4k^2-1} \sim \frac{2k}{4k^2} \sim \frac1{2k}$. Due to the comparison test, since $\sum \frac1{2k}$ diverges, so does $\sum \frac{2k}{4k^2-1}$. Must have confused it with something else.

Answer (score 4):

You have
$$\frac{2k}{4k^2-1} \sim \frac{1}{2k}$$

so the series diverges.

Comment: I think it is clearer to use $\gt$ here because then you have a direct and consistent comparison.

Comment: I think the comparison is enough clear, direct and consistent ;) But you are right, $>$ could have done the job !

Answer (score 2):

If you know Taylor series, one thing which could be interesting is to notice that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {2k}{4k^2-1}x^{2k}=\frac{1}{2} x \tanh ^{-1}(x)+\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(x)}{2 x}-\frac{1}{2}$$ and when $x\to 1$, $\tanh ^{-1}(x)\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @TheSilverDoe's answer...

The sum is approximately $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k}.$$

Note that this is $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{16}+\dots$$

Group the sum as follows:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{16}\right)+\dots$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\ge\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\ge\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}\ge\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{16}\ge\frac{1}{4}$$

And so on. The reason for the last two is because $\frac{1}{6}>\frac{1}{8}$, and $2\cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$. Same logic for the next one, and on and on, for infinity.

Therefore, the series is divergent and leads to $\infty$.

Comment: Also, you could simply say that it's divergent as it's equal to half the harmonic series, which is equal to $\infty$ as well.

Comment: True, but in case one didn't know *why* the harmonic series diverges, I explained an elementary solution here @A-levelStudent

Comment: your explanation is flawless, I was merely adding a by-the-way comment. :) Well done as well for being knowledgeable about reasonably high level maths at your age :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty passionate in contest math and I try to learn as much as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

As noticed the series diverges, more in detail we have that

$$\frac{2k}{4k^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{4k^2-1}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)+\frac12\frac1{2n+1}-\frac12=$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)-\frac{n}{2n+1}$$

and since

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k+\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$

we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{4k^2-1}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k+\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}-\frac{n}{2n+1}=\frac12H_n+A_{2n}-\frac{n}{2n+1}\to \infty$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{2k}{4k^2-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)=A_{2n}-\frac{n}{2n+1}\to \log 2-\frac12$$